# Spark streaming if(!rdd.partitions.isEmpty) not working

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, kafka-consumer-api, dstream

I'm trying to create a dStream from a kafka server and then do some transformations on that stream. I have included a catch for if the stream is empty (`if(!rdd.partitions.isEmpty)`); however, even when no events are being published to the kafka topic, the `else` statement is never reached.

```
val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](ssc, kafkaParams, topics)

stream.foreachRDD { rdd =>
    if(!rdd.partitions.isEmpty) {

        val message = rdd.map((x$2) => x$2._2).collect().toList.map(parser)

        val val = message(0)

    } else println("empty stream...")

    ssc.start() 
    ssc.awaitTermination()

}
```

Is there an alternative statement I should use to check if the stream is empty when using `KafkaUtils.createDirectStream` rather than `createStream`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `RDD.isEmpty` instead of `RDD.partitions.isEmpty` which adds a check to see if the underlying partition actually has elements:

```
stream.foreachRDD { rdd =>
  if(!rdd.isEmpty) {
    // Stuff
  }
}
```

The reason `RDD.partitions.isEmpty` isn't working is that there exists a partition inside the `RDD`, but that partition itself is empty. But from the view of `partitions` which is an `Array[Partition]`, it isn't empty.